# How to make a program wait between two timed actions

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to develop a simple SimonSays app for Windows Phone 8.

In order to make the sequence visible to users, I am using an array (`tasti`) filled with keys index, and a `for` cycle that checks the array and dims the button.

I wrote this code:

```
   int livello = 1;
   double opac = 0.3;
    void IniziaGioco()
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer5 = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer5.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
        timer5.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < livello; i++)
        {
            switch (tasti[i])
            {
                case 1:
                    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
                    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 300);
                    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(DiventaOpaco1);
                    Button1.Opacity = opac;
                    SuonoBottone1.Play();
                    timer.Start();
                    timer5.Start();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    DispatcherTimer timer2 = new DispatcherTimer();
                    timer2.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 300);
                    timer2.Tick += new EventHandler(DiventaOpaco2);
                    Button2.Opacity = opac;
                    SuonoBottone2.Play();
                    timer2.Start();
                    timer5.Start();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    DispatcherTimer timer3 = new DispatcherTimer();
                    timer3.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 300);
                    timer3.Tick += new EventHandler(DiventaOpaco3);
                    Button3.Opacity = opac;
                    SuonoBottone3.Play();
                    timer3.Start();
                    timer5.Start();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    DispatcherTimer timer4 = new DispatcherTimer();
                    timer4.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 300);
                    timer4.Tick += new EventHandler(DiventaOpaco4);
                    Button4.Opacity = opac;
                    SuonoBottone4.Play();
                    timer4.Start();
                    timer5.Start();
                    break;
            }
        }
```

`timer1` `timer2` `timer3` and `timer4` work properly and dim buttons the right way.

I wanted to use `timer5` in order to make my code "wait" for 1 second before dimming the next button, but it doesn't work, as buttons dim at the same time.

Is timer the best way? How can make my code work?

Comment: Seems all logic are same but why to use separate timers 1,2,3,4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use timer to achieve this. But IMO best solution would be `async/await` along with `Task.delay`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < livello; i++)
{
   // Your switch case
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Change your method signature as follows

```
async void IniziaGioco()
```

Comment: How do I have to change IniziaGioco() signature?

Answer (score 1):

You could use AutoResetEvent.WaitOne(int) instead of using the timer. I refer to this overload of the AutoResetEvent.WaitOne() method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189907.aspx. If you never provide a Set() event, the timer runs out and the next line of code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the asynchronous Task programming: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

Qoute: *The Async and Await keywords in Visual Basic and the async and await keywords in C# are the heart of async programming. By using those two keywords, you can use resources in the .NET Framework or the Windows Runtime to create an asynchronous method almost as easily as you create a synchronous method. Asynchronous methods that you define by using async and await are referred to as async methods.*

```
// you get somthing like this:
SuonoBottone1.Play();
await Task.Delay(1000);
SuonoBottone2.Play();
await Task.Delay(1000);
SuonoBottone3.Play();
await Task.Delay(1000);
```